# Parent and child relationship not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not quite sure how to phrase my question, so please forgive me. My plan was to create giant images of letters that make up the words "Hello World". I wanted to have these words nest inside of the big boxes and later decided to have each word be inside a smaller box. In the picture, I have created a small box (the sized has not been permanently set, I was just testing). But when I created the second small box, it flew out of the big box. In my `index.html` file, the `<div>` for the second small box was nested inside the big box `div`.

Here is the code:

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <div class = "box">

      <div class = "hello-box"></div>

        <div class = "h-left"></div>

        <div class = "h-mid"></div>

        <div class = "h-right"></div>

      </div>

      <div class = "world-box">

      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

STYLE.CSS

```
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

.hello-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.world-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

RESULT

[image]

Any help would very appreciated!!!

Comment: Use flexbox... or table if you want something backward compatible. The problem here is because `<div>`s are, by default, `display:block;`, so they break a line... and you have those huge margins, which is what makes that bottom box below the large box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>H</div>
      <div>E</div>
      <div>L</div>
      <div>L</div>
      <div>O</div>
      <div>W</div>
      <div>O</div>
      <div>R</div>
      <div>L</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

using flexbox

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're able to modify the HTML, the easiest way to fix this would be to simply shift your `.world-box` `<div>` to be *inside* of your `.box` `<div>`:

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

.hello-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.world-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="hello-box"></div>
    <div class="h-left"></div>
    <div class="h-mid"></div>
    <div class="h-right"></div>
    <div class="world-box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahh... I see. Thank you so much for the help and quick reply!!

Answer (score 1):

I would actually create a function that would put anything you want into some kind of wrapper, like so:

```js
/* js/external.js */
//<![CDATA[
var doc, bod, M, I, S, Q, special, unspecial, shuffle, ReaderBoard, autoBoard, randBoard; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
special = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
unspecial = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
}
shuffle = function(array){
  var a = array.slice(), l = a.length;
  a.sort(function(b, c){
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
  return a;
}
ReaderBoard = function(outputElement){
  this.output;
  var t = this;
  this.setOutput = function(element){
    this.output = element;
    return this;
  }
  this.setOutput(outputElement);
  this.setText = function(text){
    this.output.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i=0,a=text.split(''),s,d,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
      d = M('div'); s = a[i];
      if(s === ' ')d.className = 'space';
      d.innerHTML = special(s); this.output.appendChild(d);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
autoBoard = function(outputElement, textArray, interval, noLoop){
  var rb = new ReaderBoard(outputElement), i = 0, r, l = textArray.length;
  var v = interval || 1500;
  rb.setText(textArray[0]);
  r = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if(i === l){
      if(noLoop){
        clearInterval(r); r = undefined;
        return;
      }
      else{
        i = 0;
      }
    }
    rb.setText(textArray[i]);
  }, v);
}
randBoard = function(outputElement, textArray, interval, noLoop){
  var rb = new ReaderBoard(outputElement), i = 0, r, a = shuffle(textArray), l = a.length;
  var v = interval || 1500;
  rb.setText(a[0]);
  r = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if(i === l){
      if(noLoop){
        clearInterval(r); r = undefined;
        return;
      }
      else{
        a = shuffle(a); i = 0;
      }
    }
    rb.setText(a[i]);
  }, v);
}
var rb = new ReaderBoard(I('readerboard'));
rb.setText('Hello World!');
autoBoard(I('autoboard'), ['Check this out!', "It's a reader board.", 'This one runs in order.', 'Are you not amazed?']);
autoBoard(I('noloop_autoboard'), ['Check this out!', "It's a reader board.", 'This one runs in order.', 'Are you not amazed?'], 2000, true);
randBoard(I('randboard'), ['This is Awesome!', "Isn't totally random.", 'Create Something Cool', 'Success!', 'Nice']);
randBoard(I('noloop_randboard'), ['This is Awesome!', "Isn't totally random.", 'Create Something Cool', 'Success!', 'Nice'], 3500, true);
});
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.flex_text{
  display:flex;
}
.flex_text>div{
  flex:1; background:#fff; font:bold 30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; margin:3px;
}
.flex_text>.space{
  background:#ccc; margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='flex_text' id='readerboard'></div>
  <hr />
  <div class='flex_text' id='autoboard'></div>
  <hr />
  <div class='flex_text' id='noloop_autoboard'></div>
  <hr />
  <div class='flex_text' id='randboard'></div>
  <hr />
  <div class='flex_text' id='noloop_randboard'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just a thought.

Comment: This is very cool!! I never thought about using JavaScript for this part. This is will be noted, thank you so much!